# SSRS Code export

Tags: reporting-services

I have an Item in the Header in SSRS 2005. It is filled based on code that returns a value based on a report item in the body. When viewing on screen it shows correctly. When printing or exporting, it does not show up.

The code takes a string then depending on the value returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can check, is to make sure the Property "PrintOnFirstPage" is set to TRUE.
You can verify this, but selecting the HEADER, and going to it's properties.
Alternatively, you can also go to the Report Properties, and there is a checkbox there labelled Print Header on First Page.

Comment: It is set to print on first page.